# CORS Policy Blocked Error with JSON, but Switching Header Type Fixes Error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, cors

I made this simple input form that displays data when I add info to them.

So I followed this tutorial and they made this header with `application/json` for rendering json data through input fields.

```
                   let url = 'http://localhost:3000/';
                    let h = new Headers()

                    h.append('Content-type', 'application/json')
                    let req = new Request(url, {
                        headers: h,
                        body: json,
                        method: 'POST'
                    })
```

However, reading the MDN docs, it shows that there's only 3 content types and I don't understand which one to use when trying to display JSON data.

According to the docs it says

```
 It also needs to have a MIME type of its parsed value (ignoring parameters) 
 of either application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain.
```

So if I just switch my code to this, the error goes away, but I don't know if this is the correct method.

```
h.append('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data')
let req = new Request(url, {
    headers: h,
    body: json,
    method: 'POST'
})
```

In the tutorial, he said it only shows the error because he is using a different port number and not addressing it in the server?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWJhE7Licjs timestamp 10:40

However, everything before that it worked completely fine until he added the json data option?

Server code

```
                const http = require('http');

                const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
                req.on('data', function (data) {
                    //handle data as it is received... for POST requests
                });
                req.on('end', function () {
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                    res.writeHead(200, 'OK');

                    res.end('{ "data": "just a plain old json reply" }');
                });
                });

                server.listen(3000, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('bad things');
                    return;
                }
                console.log('listening on port 3000');
                });
```

Comment: What is the context for that code? Is it in a browser? Where are `Headers` and `Request` coming from?

Comment: When making a web request the content type should match the content you are sending. form-data doesn't match json string content, but in terms of CORS, does result in the request not needing a preflight... which can resolve CORS errors if the target server doesn't support preflights.

Comment: but application/json isn't shown as an option on the http mdn docs? so how would you remove that cors error?

Comment: You configure the server to properly support preflights.

Comment: I added my server code and it has json, but not sure what else to fix?

Answer (score -1):

CORS requires [a preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) be granted permissions before a browser will make a cross-origin request that isn't Simple.

If the port the request is being sent to doesn't match the port the HTML document that initiated the request was served from, then it is a cross-origin request.

One way that a request can be make preflighted is to send [a type of data you can't send with an HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype).

JSON is not a type of data you can send with an HTML form, so if you send JSON data then a preflight request is needed.

In this case, you are just lying about what type of data you are sending. Presumably you are also setting up the server to ignore the `Content-Type` request header and try to parse the request body as JSON regardless.

A better approach would be to tell the truth about what type of content you are sending, and configure the server to grant permission to the preflight.

Comment: I added my server code below my post, but it clearly shows content type json yet I still got the cors error?

Comment: @makerbaker — (a) You haven't special cased OPTIONS requests (which are the type of request sent for a preflight). (b) The `Content-Type` of the response is not the same as the headers CORS allows the request to include (which are determined by the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header).  (I strongly recommend not reinventing the wheel and using Express and the CORS middleware you can find on NPM).